# Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function and $ B \subseteq Y$ is countable then $ f^{-1} $(B) is countable.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function and $ B \subseteq Y$ is countable then $ f^{-1}   $(B) is countable.

My definition of countable is the following: A non-empty set $X$ is said to be countable if there exists a subset $I$ of $Z^+$ and a one to one onto function $f: I \rightarrow X$.

This is my first proofs writing course.  I am having a hard time with the idea of countable.  I feel like a lot of the "proofs" I have done so show something is countable is just to make a list.

I am not sure if that is how I would go about proving this statement or not? Any suggestions or explanations would be helpful!

Comment: What if B is one number (e.g. y = 1). Does $f^{-1}(B)$ have to be countable? To disprove this result you just need one counterexample, which would consist of an X, a Y, an f and a B.

Comment: Are you forgetting some hypothesis? (Say injective or bijective).

Comment: No it does not say anything about the function having to be one to one or onto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong.

Take $$\begin{array} .f:\mathbb{R}& \to & \mathbb{Z} \\x &\mapsto &\lfloor x \rfloor \end{array}$$

Then $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, but $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{R}$ is not

Comment: What do the brackets for your function mean?

Comment: The floor function, take the integer part. $\lfloor \pi \rfloor = 3$

Comment: can it be any function as long as you define your domain to be real numbers and the range to be the integers?

Comment: Yes, you're right. This was just a concrete exemple

Comment: I was just trying to come up with something I am more familiar with then the floor function

Comment: any other ideas? I mean can you just say let $f: R \rightarrow Z$ be the function $x \rightarrow x^2$